# Populating textbox with mysql data values from combobox selection c#

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox, textbox, populate

I am trying to populate my text boxes with the values in my database so when a user selects a name of a teacher from the combobox, the text-boxes will populate with their contact details. This is the code I have so far. There are no errors however the textboxes are still blank when I select a value from combo box.

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection cs = new MySqlConnection(connectionSQL);
        cs.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from Teacher WHERE name='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", cs);

        MySqlCommandBuilder cmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);

        da.Fill(ds);


        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {


            NameBox.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
            AddressBox.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["address"].ToString();

        }
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

I've got to believe that based on your code the problem lies right here:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)
```

if you only had one item in the list **or** the user selected the first item, the query would run but the text boxes wouldn't populate.

Comment: I altered the code and now it is throwing up this instance Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I checked and it looks like my dataset is empty even though all the information is correct

Comment: @user2187795, on what line? And when you're in the debugger, which of the following is `null`: `NameBox`, `AddressBox`, `ds`, `Tables[0]`, `Rows[0]`, `Rows[0]["name"]`, or `Rows[0]["address"]`?

Comment: @user2187795, do me a favor and change your `SELECT` statement to be `SELECT name, address FROM Teacher WHERE `.

Answer (score 0):

```
AddressBox.DataBind();
NameBox.DataBind();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: after assigning the value to the textbox, DataBind() method is used to bind the value from the database to textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You're querying the database before you verify the selected index and you should be checking for a selected index greater than -1, not 0.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectIndex < 0) 
    {
        // Don't want to suffer database hit if nothing is selected
        // Simply clear text boxes and return
        NameBox.Text = "";
        AddressBox.Text = "";
    }
    else 
    {
        MySqlConnection cs = new MySqlConnection(connectionSQL);
        cs.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        // You only need to select the address since you already have the name unless 
        // they are displayed differently and you want the database display to show
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select address from Teacher WHERE name='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", cs);

        MySqlCommandBuilder cmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);

        da.Fill(ds);

        NameBox.Text = comboBox1.Text;
        AddressBox.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["address"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Also, if the name is displayed differently in the combo box than in the database in a way that's easy to miss, such as an extra space between first and last name or something else that's hard to visibly detect, that could be causing the query to not match.